# Datagrid WPF issue column not binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

I wanted to know how to use converter in DataColumn. When using the DESCR column from the Ord_C_Order_Status table. It is not allowing to use.
DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ORDER_STATUS,Converter={StaticResource OrderStatusConverter}}"

I want to use converter for this Binding for DESCR but it doesn't allow.

```
   <dxg:GridControl DataSource="{Binding Data}"
             AutoExpandAllGroups="True"
             ShowBorder="True"
             Background="{StaticResource Background1}">
   <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
    <!--FieldName="ORDER_KEY"-->
    <dxg:GridColumn Name="colORDER_KEY"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ORDER_STATUS,Converter=       {StaticResource             OrderStatusConverter}}"
                    Header="Order key" />
    <dxg:GridColumn Name="colPAT_NUMBER"
                    Header="PAT_NUMBER"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FACILITY_KEY}" />
```

here is the data grid columns:

```
            <dxg:GridColumn Name="colORDER_KEY"
                            FieldName="ORDER_KEY"
                            ReadOnly="True"
                            Header="Order key" />
            <dxg:GridColumn Name="colPAT_NUMBER"
                            Header="PAT_NUMBER"
                            FieldName="PAT_NUMBER"
                            ReadOnly="True" />
            <dxg:GridColumn Name="colFACILITY_KEY"
                            FieldName="FACILITY_KEY"
                            Header="FACILITY_KEY"
                            ReadOnly="True" />
            <dxg:GridColumn Name="colPATIENT_ID"
                            Header="PATIENT_ID"
                            FieldName="PATIENT_ID"
                            ReadOnly="True" />
            <dxg:GridColumn Name="colMRN"
                            FieldName="ORDER_TYPE_KEY"
                            Header="ORDER_TYPE_KEY"
                            ReadOnly="True" />
            <dxg:GridColumn Name="colORDER_STATUS"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ORDER_STATUS}"
                            Header="ORDER_STATUS"
                            ReadOnly="True" />
```

Comment: its not displaying any data. actually i really want to display the DESCRF which corresponds to order status but that also show blank only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably need to overwrite the Column's Template to use the converter

I don't know what version of DataGrid you're using, but it should be something like this:

```
<dxg:GridColumn Name="colORDER_KEY" Header="Order key">
    <dxg:GridColumn.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ORDER_STATUS,
                       Converter={StaticResource OrderStatusConverter}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </dxg:GridColumn.ItemTemplate>
</dxg:GridColumn>
```

Comment: We are using devexpress I should have mentioned. thanks I will try your idea. I get 2 error messages:

Comment: We are using devexpress I should have mentioned. thanks I will try your idea. I get 2 error messages: Error 5 The tag 'GridColumn.ItemTemplate' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid'. Line 50 Position 22. C:\LLA\OPTFDashboard\LLA.Dashboard.Plugins.Orders\Views\OrderView.xaml 50 22 LLA.Dashboard.Plugins.Orders
Error 6 The attachable property 'ItemTemplate' was not found in type 'GridColumn'. C:\LLA\OPTFDashboard\LLA.Dashboard.Plugins.Orders\Views\OrderView.xaml 50 22 LLA.Dashboard.Plugins.Orders

Comment: @booksman Try `CellTemplate` or `EditTemplate` instead of `ItemTemplate`

Answer (score 0):

Try using CellTemplate. Also, in your Binding Path, prefix your field with the 'Data'

(e.g. Data.ORDER_STATUS)

```
<dxg:GridColumn Name="colORDER_KEY" Header="Order key"> 
<dxg:GridColumn.ItemTemplate> 
    <DataTemplate> 
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Data.ORDER_STATUS, 
                   Converter={StaticResource OrderStatusConverter}}" /> 
    </DataTemplate> 
</dxg:GridColumn.ItemTemplate>
```